# Noun describing one who "acts on emotion primally"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I’m looking for a noun to describe someone who “acts on emotion primally”, or something similar.

To clarify, I’m trying to make a point about how the fanaticism of tech-fetishes (iPhone fanboyism and the like) causes people to forgo rational, sometimes even calculated, intelligent responses to criticism. Instead, people lose themselves in irrational, primal competitiveness and negativity; responses near involuntariness and waste potential value.

If any further context is desired, please let me know.

I think the closest word I’ve come to is *primal*, but I’d really like a noun and I’m not sure *primal* is as precise as it could be anyway.

**Bonus:** If you have a good antonym for the word that describes what I’m trying to say (so it’s more along the lines of what I mentioned as *rational, calculated, intelligent*) I’d love to hear it.

Comment: It's obvious: the noun form of *primal* is *primate*. Doesn't that describe them accurately?

Comment: I guess.  I like what burhan said below, though.  Primal was not precise enough in the first place.

Comment: I said it as a joke since to English speakers the word *primate*  mainly brings monkeys to mind.

Comment: SigueSigueBen is suggesting that Apple makes a monkey out of people. (Perhaps you're not familiar with the idiom.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked for a noun but then mentioned some adjectives, so I'm going to suggest [*visceral*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/visceral), which describes a 'gut response' as opposed to a reasoned, or *cerebral*, response.

Comment: I agree with visceral. Primal implies instinctive; not emotive.

Comment: These two are near-perfect, I'll live with the adjectives haha.  Thanks man!

Comment: @BOSS if it's correct, could you mark it as such? With the big greek tick?

Comment: @Pureferret I was just making sure that no other great answers came along but I am quite satisfied with this and have accepted it.

Comment: Sorry to have nagged, I've seen too many good answers being only unofficially accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Your question contains the answer: the person you describe is a [fanatic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fanatic):

> a person with an extreme and uncritical enthusiasm or zeal, as in religion or politics

Answer (score 3):

You could use ***evangelist***  although it implies that they are trying to "spread the word" rather than just blindly follow their beliefs. There must be another religious term that works, but I haven't thought of it yet.

Comment: I think you're thinking of [zealot](http://www.wordnik.com/words/zealot).

Comment: That most certainly is along the lines that I was thinking.

Comment: They are coming now: ***devotee*** or perhaps even ***acolyte***, if it isn't too esoteric a term.

Comment: An evangelist would also *proselytise*.

Answer (score 2):

Given OP's specific context, you might call them ***fetishists***. A fetishist's passion is characterized as being compulsive and irrational.

Alternatively, you could refer to them as ***the possessed*** or ***junkies***, as their actions no longer seem to be in their control.

As for antonyms, I'd pair fetishist & connoisseur (given that everyone in your example seems pro-tech), the possessed & the clear-headed, junkies & the sober.

Comment: I like the explicit comparisons you drew here.  Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a specific term for a person who acts, not on reason, but on emotional impulse. the adjective *impulsive* fits your question, so I suggest **impulsive person**.

Answer (score 2):

Apple fanboys would say they are *passionate* about that company's products. Some are *monomaniacal* or *over-zealous* or *fervid*.

Answer (score 0):

I acted on emotional impulse.  One day as we were visiting my sick mom in the hospital, she had just went through bypass surgery and we went to the hospital to spend time with her.  A nurse walked in with this beautiful hair style.  I woke from a restless night and she walked in the room to give us the results from my mom's surgery and I asked her was that her real hair. I think what made me ask that question is Gravity.  I meant no harm.  Backhanded complimenting the style and how it resembled a famous representative's hairstyle. It was none of business.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Intuitive........"using or based on what one feels to be true even wothout concious reasoning."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).